# html content in php file wont display in centos server

Tags: php, linux

I just finished testing my app in the local wamp server and transfered them to my centos VPS which is basically a lamp stack. 
The problem is, many of my .php files which have html content in them are not displayed properly in there. Here is an example

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>
            Tailor Management - Order Details
        </title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <h1>
                Order Details
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; margin-right: 10px; background-color: #fe6154; border:2px;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/blank.png" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/1.png" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/2.png" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/3.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <table id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Oid
                </th>
                <th>
                    Cusid
                </th>
                <th>
                    Type
                </th>
                <th>
                    I-Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    D-Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Quan
                </th>
                <th>
                    Rate
                </th>
                <th>
                    Price
                </th>
                <th>
                    Comments
                </th>
                <th>
                    Status
                </th>
                <th>
                    Details
                </th>

            </tr>
            <?php

            .....
                    ?>
                <form name="v_order" method="POST" action="o_processor.php">
                <?php

                ........
                ?>
                <tr style="background-color:<?php echo $color; ?>">
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name = "oid[]"  class="inp-form-oid" readonly value ="<?php echo $oid[$counter]; ?>"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name = "cusid[]" class="inp-form-oid" readonly value ="<?php echo $cusid[$counter]; ?>"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name = "type[]"  class="inp-form-oid" value ="<?php echo $otype[$counter]; ?>" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name = "idate[]"  class="inp-form-oid" value ="<?php $date = new DateTime($idate[$counter]); echo $date->format('d-m-Y'); ?>" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name = "ddate[]"  class="inp-form-oid" value ="<?php $date = new DateTime($ddate[$counter]); echo $date->format('d-m-Y'); ?>" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name = "quan[]"  class="inp-form-oid" value ="<?php echo $quan[$counter]; ?>" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name = "rate[]"  class="inp-form-oid" value ="<?php echo $rate[$counter]; ?>" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name = "price[]" class="inp-form-oid" value ="<?php echo $price[$counter]; ?>" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea name="comments[]" rows="2" cols="8"><?php echo $comments[$counter]; ?></textarea>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="ready[]"  value ="<?php echo $oid[$counter]; ?>" <?php  $status[$counter];
                            if($status[$counter] == 3){
                                echo 'checked';
                            } ?>/>Ready
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="done[]"  value ="<?php echo $oid[$counter]; ?>" <?php  $status[$counter];
                            if($status[$counter] == 4){
                                echo 'checked';
                            } ?>/>Done
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"  name ="cancel[]" value ="<?php echo $oid[$counter]; ?>"/>Cancel
                        </label>


                    </td>
                    <td>

                            <a href="detail.php?oid=<?php echo $oid[$counter];?>" target="_blank">
                                Order Details
                            </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <a href="cust_detail.php?oid=<?php echo $oid[$counter];?>" target="_blank">
                                Cust Details
                            </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <a href="emp_detail.php?oid=<?php echo $oid[$counter];?>" target="_blank">
                                Emp Details
                            </a>

                    </td>

                </tr>

                <?php
                $color = "#ffff";
            }
            ?>
            <div align="center">
                <table style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top: 40px;">
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="width:150px; height: 60px;" />
                    </td>
                </table>
            </div>
            </form>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code when running on my production server displays a page that looks like this

[image: Page when running on local wamp server]

But when running on the centos VPS this same page is looking like this

[image: page when running on centos]

I have checked that the sql queries are running just fine by manually running them the sql connectivity is fine too.

I have done a clean install of the lamp for 3 time now but still getting the same error. Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening? Some suggestion on how to solve this would be great.

P.S:- I tried to ask this question in serverfault but it wont let me post the screenshots because I didn't have 10 reputation points in there, so sorry if this is not the right place to ask this question.

Comment: Look at your server logs. There's probably a difference between the PHP installations that's causing the error. The server logs will tell you what is going on.

Comment: @MikeW my development server is running php 5.3.13 where as the centos is running 5.3.3 do you think that can cause this error?

Comment: I doubt the version is significant, but your server logs will tell you. Look there first.

Comment: [Fri Oct 11 01:12:14 2013] [error] [client 108.162.222.156] PHP Warning:  phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead in /var/www/html/info.php on line 2

Comment: Those are the recent logs I am setting up the date.timezone as of now

Comment: OK adding the correct date.timezone setting fixed it !!! thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by **Mike W** on checking the server log I found that the error in there was

> [Fri Oct 11 01:12:14 2013] [error] [client 108.162.222.156] PHP
>   Warning: phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are required to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for
>   'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead in /var/www/html/info.php on line 2

Modifying the php.ini file to add the correct **date.timezone** did the work and now the page is displaying correctly

Answer (score -1):

I found two error

1) please remove the extra php tags and `.....` from your code

```
<?php

        .....
                ?>
```

2) there is a extra `}` after `$color = "#ffff";`

```
 <?php
                $color = "#ffff";
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: For whatever reason the OP had stripped out the PHP from his code. This is not the cause of his problem.